# iPython: print() function supresses the direct variable output

Tags: python, printing, output, ipython

It must be something simple that I just missed, but I'm still struggling to find the answer.
I use iPuthon. Suppose, I copied several lines at once from some other source, like a webpage. Also suppose, that the fragment has a variable on a separate line, in order to print it out (in accord with Python's syntax):

```
myList = ['Abc', 25, 'Yes', 'No']
myList
```

The result, as I expect it (and as it comes out in fact):

```
Out[5]: ['Abc', 25, 'Yes', 'No']
```

Now, let's add just one line to the end of this fragment:

```
myList = ['Abc', 25, 'Yes', 'No']
myList
print('voila!')
```

and all of a sudden, there will be no trace of the list printed, but only the print('voila') output is visible:

```
In [6]: myList = ['Abc', 25, 'Yes', 'No'] 
   ...: myList 
   ...: print('voila!')                                                                             
voila!
```

Exactly same thing happens in Jupyter, or in Komodo IDE, except there I don't even have a possibility (well, generally speaking) to enter the lines one-by-one. The workaround I was using, is to use print() function to output the object, but this is lousy - the native output in most cases is way more advanced.
My understanding is, the print() function spits it over the top of old output, thus in fact replacing what was there, but this, true or false, still doesn't help.
I tried googling, but w/no success - maybe, I could not formulate the search string well enough - you know, it is an art of a kind..
Please poke my nose into it!

Comment: That's not "in accord with Python's syntax". That's an interactive convenience. You're probably used to IPython's version of that in particular, which does all sorts of additional stuff beyond any default Python behavior.

Comment: Putting `myList` on a line by itself is not any sort of Python "display this" syntax. If it was, the `print` on the next line wouldn't affect it.

Comment: Hi Monica, thanks for looking into it. Well, I'm not exactly "used to" anything regarding Python, as I just started using it, days back then. This "display it" functionality could be something which I could live without, but - this feature seems to be pretty handy when you work with i.g. Pandas (in Jupyter). Pandas' "display it" output vs print(), looks like NY steak vs boiled meat - same calories and proteins, but way better tasting. All the bold and shadows, it does help reading, I bet. So, at least one is certain to me: the Pandas developers do pay attention to this feature.

Comment: That's IPython sending the dataframe's `to_html()` output to a frontend that can support rich display. If you want to invoke that manually, you can call [`IPython.display.display(your_df)`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display). Don't get this confused for any sort of built-in Python functionality.

Comment: Just use `display` instead of `print`

Comment: Bingo!! Thanks, Monica, that seems to fix my problem. From now on, I have to pronounce that spell every time I want to see my precious DF - plus import the IPython to all my scripts - in case I want it to function everywhere, and best way possible. Well, it probably worth that. Thanks! I hope you don't mind if I post this as an answer here (with reference, of course) - or would you do it yourself?

Comment: It looks like `display` is automatically imported by default in IPython, so you can call `display(your_df)` without needing a manual import. (Still, remember that this is all IPython functionality. None of it will work in an actual program.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the issue.  In an IPython session:

```
In [61]: x = [1,2,3] 
    ...: x 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                        
Out[61]: [1, 2, 3]
In [62]: x = [1,2,3] 
    ...: x 
    ...: print(x)                                                               
[1, 2, 3]
In [63]: None                                                                   
In [64]:
```

`Out[61]` is displayed, and added to the out history.  It's the last line of the of the [61] block.  In [62] the last line is a `print`, which displays text, and returns `None`.  `None` is not displayed or added to `Out`.

A plain interactive Python session the history is more limited, just '_'.  But even there the `print` output is not cached.

Here's further evidence that the last line (or last statement) is displayed and cached.  The `print` in [62] does over write `x`:

```
In [64]: x = [1,2,3] 
    ...: x 
    ...: 'yes'                                                                  
Out[64]: 'yes'
In [65]: _                                                                      
Out[65]: 'yes
In [66]: x = [1,2,3]; x; 'yes'                                                  
Out[66]: 'yes'
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "native output", but may be it's the `repr` display.  The default for `print` is the `str`, which may be more compact.  For example with an array:

```
In [67]: x = np.array([1,2,3])                                                  
In [68]: print(x)                                                               
[1 2 3]
In [69]: x                                                                      
Out[69]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [70]: print(repr(x))                                                         
array([1, 2, 3])
In [71]: print(str(x))                                                          
[1 2 3]
```

I usually use the terminal `ipython` so don't see the fancier display.  But I just realized that in a `notebook` I can use

```
display(df)
print(df)
```

and get both the highlighted display and the plain text.

in the plain console:

```
In [84]: display(x);print(x)                                                    
array([1, 2, 3])
[1 2 3]
```